# MS Access, Combobox, select fields bases on query, How do I weight the result fields

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a db where based on user input a series of comboboxes will populate.

```
Private Sub txtUserInput_AfterUpdate()
cbo1.RowSource = "Select txtValue from tbl1 where (txtValue=" & [Forms]![Form1]![txtValue] & ")"
cbo1.Requery
End Sub
```

Easy enough.

But I would like the order of the results to change based on weights I assign. For example, each instance I update blue is first 25% of the time, red is first 25% of the time and yellow is first 50% of the time.

EDIT 1:

For example (thank you Gene 2):

```
txtValue1    Blue
txtValue1    Red
txtValue1    Yellow
txtValue2    Ford
txtValue2    Dodge
txtValue3    Violet
txtValue3    Lilly
txtValue3    Poppy
```

When the user inputs txtValue1 into txtValue, the combo box reads:

```
Blue
Red
Yellow
```

I would like that order to change each time the box is activated based on probabilities I assign.

EDIT 2:

So John, the user goes to the form the first time.

```
Blue
Red
Yellow
```

The second time the user goes to the form.

```
Red
Blue
Yellow
```

Third time.

```
Yellow
Red
Blue
```

Fourth time.

```
Yellow
Red
Blue
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are blue, red, and yellow? what do you assign these to? and how?  Could you post some example data?

Comment: you're probalby going to have to write a custom function to do this. Maybe something that generates a random number between 1 and 100, if the random number lands between 1 and 25 then order blue first, 26-50, red first, 51-100 order yellow first.

Comment: They are vendors. I'm trying to balance the workload between them. Right now users tend to just pick the first one or their favorite. I like the random number idea. I'll try to work that out in vba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add ORDER BY the weights you have assigned

```
cbo1.RowSource = "Select txtValue from tbl1 where (txtValue=" & [Forms]![Form1]![txtValue] & " ORDER BY weight)"
```

Comment: I must say i cannot understand the part "based on the probabilities" . If i understood you correctly then you need a table with this structure :ID / Color / Weight .You have something like 1/ Blue / 10,   2 / Red /20...